# Enumeration in caption messes with labels

Tags: labels, autoref

I am trying to use an enumeration inside the caption of a table. However, this messes the label of the table, when I later try to reference it using `autoref`. See figure and sample document following.

[image: incorrect label for referenced item]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{plex-otf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{Caption Enumerations and Labels}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[h]
% TOC title is mandatory, or compilation breaks?
%\caption{Here is a table showing stuff, with an enum in caption:
\caption[TOC caption]{Here is a table showing stuff, with an enum in caption:
\begin{enumerate*}[label=\itshape\alph*\upshape.]
\item first item,
\item second item,
\item third item.
\end{enumerate*}
}
\label{tab:second}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  first & second & third \\
  \toprule
  1     & 2      & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\section{Incorrect Label}
Here's a reference to the table: \autoref{tab:second}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to restore the proper label, just after the `caption` braces close, so that `autoref` will produce a Table reference?

Note that the number produced by `autoref` is the correct one, and is not picked by the preceding enumeration.

Comment: Not tested.  Try putting the label *inside* the caption, before the `enumerate`.

Comment: So you want to reference various table cells, rather than the table itself?

Comment: Aha!  \@currentlabel is local while \@currentHref is global..  (I might also add that the enumerate is run twice.)

Comment: The easiest solution is to lose the enumerate and  simply type in a,b,c etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I ended up just adding the letters manually. I guess this glitch is the cost of not requiring a strict placement for \label (e.g. allowing it even inside the caption). And I'm not sure it even worths reporting it as a bug (very likely to end up in the wontfix bucket).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Tried that already before posting. Didn't work.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you elaborate on the "enumerate is run twice"?

Comment: I noticed that the final counter value was six, not three.  One possible  cause is the singlelinecheck.  Another is when the caption is written to the aux file.